# App Crashing on Start Up - Null pointer

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am getting this LogCat from an app that resumes (after the `Activity` has long been gone (not everytime).  It is actually a specific `Fragment`, so it's when the `FragmentActivity` resumes.

```
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.---.---.DebtDataSource.payoffDebt(DebtDataSource.java:229)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.---.---.PlannerFragment$PlannerTask.doInBackground(PlannerFragment.java:131)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at com.---.---.PlannerFragment$PlannerTask.doInBackground(PlannerFragment.java:1)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-18 18:45:33.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7593):     ... 4 more
```

The Main Activity has this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    datasource.close();
    finish();

}
```

Nothing in the `onResume()`.

The `Fragment` calls an `AsyncTask` when the `Activity` has been in the background after along time.

The problem is `DoInBackground` base on the Log. (`PlannerFragment`)

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


    if (paymentTotal > allFee) {

        totalMonths = datasource.payoffDebt(Double.valueOf(columnDebtTotal)); // this is line 131
        finalDate = datasource.getDate(totalMonths);
        allFeeLife = datasource.getLiftimeFees();

    }

    return null;

}
```

Then the Nullpointer is after Nullpointer tries to grab data from my SQLite DB.

(`DebtDataSource` Class)

```
public int payoffDebt(Double totalDebt) {
Cursor c = null;

if (DebtPlanner.PlanType.equals("highint")) { // line 229 -- NULL CRASH!
    c = database.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM debt ORDER BY CAST("
            + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_APR + " as integer) DESC;", null);
}
```

Again, this only crashes when the `Activity` resumes after a long time in the background (long enough to require the `task` above in the `onActivityCreated` to be called again).

Comment: what is line 229 of DebtDataSource?

Comment: @panini  I have it commented right above in last block of code.

Comment: Either `DebtPlanner` or `PlanType` is null. Please verify this or post code where you are initializing them..

Comment: `DebtPlanner `is a class that extends `Application`.  `PlanType` is a `String`.  I'll add more.  In `DebtPlanner` class, `public static String PlanType;`

Comment: I think I need to initialize `PlanType`.

Comment: Yes.. if you haven't done so. That should fix the problem :)

Comment: @AmulyaKhare That did.  Feel free to mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullPointerException` is  thrown when executing: `DebtPlanner.PlanType.equals("highint")`. There are two possible reasons:

(1) `DebtPlanner` is `null`, or (2) `PlanType` is `null`

**Solution** Verify that both these fields have been initialized and are not null when this line is executed. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[LoaderManager](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) and AsyncTaskLoader are better than AsyncTask for longer operations.